# How to implemente a Tile which can be updated every 1 minute?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

In windows phone store, there are have an app named TimeMe Tile, it can update current time on Tile every 1 minute, I am very curious how it is implemented, as far as know, the period of background task is 30 minutes.

Here is this app's link:
http://www.windowsphone.com/zh-cn/store/app/timeme-tile/ef6099f2-41dd-4bad-9fa1-8f4143386194

Thank you.

Comment: It's possible that the app uses push notifications. One way to make sure would be to turn on airplane mode and see if the tile still updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have predictable tile information (like the time) then you can schedule the tile notifications ahead of time with the ScheduledTileNotification class. Scheduled notifications will fire even if the app itself is not running. The app only needs to run (in the foreground or as a background task) to schedule the notification.

You can schedule a tile to update every minute for the next hour something like the following:

```
int min = 0;
for(min=0;min<60;min++)
{    
    // Create a tile template with whatever we want to show
    XmlDocument tileXml = GenerateTileTemplate(min);
    // Schedule it for min minutes from now
    DateTime dueTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(min);
    ScheduledTileNotification scheduledTile = new ScheduledTileNotification(tileXml, dueTime);
    TileUpdateManager.createTileUpdaterForApplication().AddToSchedule(scheduledTile);
}
```

For a fuller example see [How to schedule a tile notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh868223(v=win.10).aspx).

If the tile needs to have more timely data that can't be predicted then you'd need to push a notification from off-system to include that information more often than the app can get CPU time.